# What happens if I have DllImport (C# .NET) for an API not supported by the operating system version

Tags: c#, .net, windows, native, dllimport

I need to call some system APIs, which are only supported from Windows Vista client or Windows 2008 Server onwards. So, I'm using DllImport and invoking those methods. However, my WPF application has to also support older platforms (although very few clients). So, my plan is to detect the operating system first and then display a different screen instead of calling those unsupported APIs. But I want to know the expected behaviour

- Will the application fail to load or even run on older platforms as the DllImport fails? I couldn't find any documentation about this.

If that's the case then I will have to either completely avoid using these APIs or have to build a separate version of application for older operating systems.

I will test this myself later this and update here accordingly. However, can anyone please guide me the recommended way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: I would go for different "versions" of the program, instead of trying to make the program work on any version of the S.O.

Comment: No, this is totally fine. This is what DllImport is supposed to be used for. Note that version-detection is hard; prefer attempting to call the function and handling failure.

Comment: It is expected that you check the OSVersion and display a different screen so the api call won't fail with an exception.  And that you'll actually test this on an old OS.  Pretty unclear why this has to be spelled out, what's the point of this question?

Comment: Calling a `DllImport` function at runtime will trigger the error, `EntryPointNotFoundException`. So you can simply elect not to call the functions that are not implemented on the prevailing platform.

Comment: Thanks Cody Gray and David Hefferman. From your answers, it appears that the application won't crash or throw exception before calling the function.

Comment: @HansPassant - I mainly wanted to know whether the application will even fail to start. I couldn't find specific documentation easily. If it fails to run, I won't even get the opportunity to check the OS and display another screen. In that case, I wanted to know if there is any alternative solutions. At the moment, I don't have VM setup for older OS version to test the code myself. Of course, I will get this tested it at some point. But, nevertheless, I believe the question is useful for other developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assembly will load without any problems. Calling the imported unmanaged function will raise a [`EntryPointNotFoundException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.entrypointnotfoundexception.aspx).

See the remarks of the exception documentation: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.entrypointnotfoundexception.aspx#Anchor_6). It states that the exception is raised if:

> The call to a function in a Windows DLL cannot be resolved because the function cannot be found.

So you can simply wrap the call to the function in a `try`-`catch` and handle cases where the function is not present this way.